# Why does echo display the view and the return statement doesn't display anything

Tags: php, laravel

These is my `create` and `store` functions:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->except('_token');
    $validator = $this->validator($data);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->store($data);
    $request->find($request);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permintaan berhasil diinput');
}

public function store(array $data){
    Permintaan::create([
        'kdInventaris' => $data['kodeInventaris'],
        'namaInventaris' => $data['namaInventaris'],
        'jenis' => $data['optInventaris'],
        'jumlah' => $data['jumlah'],
        'spesifikasi' => $data['spesifikasi'],
        'keterangan' => $data['keterangan'],
    ]);
}
```

When it is redirecting, it works but got a blank page again and is replaced with echo.

It works, but has this message and got a successful redirect:

> "HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2015
>   16:04:33 GMT Location: http://localhost:8000/permintaan Redirecting to
>   http://localhost:8000/permintaan."

I wonder if the error has anything to do with my `return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permintaan berhasil diinput');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `redirect()` means you are trying to Return a named route

If you do use `redirect()` then you should give a named route such as `return redirect()->route('someroute');`

You cannot use it for `back`. But, If you wanted to so, then you can simply redirect back by

```
Redirect::back()->withMessage('Permintaan berhasil diinput')
```

or even you can use

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Permintaan berhasil diinput');
```

Here you can learn more about the Redirects in [Laravel's Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

Comment: Wow. You're my hero. Thanks:)